# strongloop: hide default method on PersistedModel

Tags: javascript, mongodb, strongloop

I have a model defined as a `PersistedModel`, hence is related to a mongodb collection. I want to achieve the following:

1. default *crud* methods to be hidden
2. a custom remote method to be **exposed** and mapped on route `GET /` (which is a `myModel.find()` by default)

So far, I couldn't get both requirements: if I set the model to public, it comes with the whole set of built-in method mapped on *standard* routes, if I set it non-public even my custom remotes are hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you're looking for is:

```
MyModel.disableRemoteMethod(name, [isStatic])
```

Here are the [API docs](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#model-disableremotemethod).

Unfortunately, you need to disable each method individually...

Another solution would be to create two different models, one public and one not (Your can change the `Public` boolean to false in the `server/model-config.json` file. You do not need to attach the "Public" Model to a datasource.

```
"MyPublicModel": {
  "dataSource": null,
  "public": true
},
"MyPrivateModel": {
  "datasource": "db",
  "public": false
}
```

The public-facing model would be of base-class `Model` while the non-public model would still be a `PersistedModel` with none of its endpoints exposed. You can access the functions of the "Private" model by calling `MyPublicModel.app.models.MyPrivateModel` within the `MyPublicModel.js` file.

(Please comment if you need any clarifications).

Comment: thanks for sharing. I personally feel comfortable with the option below, by defining a disableAllMethodsButRemotes function

Comment: oh nice, didn't realize that it was you that found the workaround!

Answer (score 0):

I solved by this *ol' dirty* workaround. I found it at this address: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/651.

I finally came out with this snippet:

in my model file

```
module.exports = function(myModel) {
    utils.disableAllMethodsButRemotes(myModel);
};
```

in my `utils.js` library file:

```
exports.disableAllMethodsBut = function(model, methodsToExpose) {
    if (model && model.sharedClass) {
        methodsToExpose = methodsToExpose || [];

        var modelName = model.sharedClass.name;
        var methods = model.sharedClass.methods();
        var relationMethods = [];
        var hiddenMethods = [];

        try {
            Object.keys(model.definition.settings.relations).forEach(function(relation) {
            relationMethods.push({
                name: '__findById__' + relation,
                isStatic: false
            });
            relationMethods.push({
                name: '__destroyById__' + relation,
                isStatic: false
            });
            relationMethods.push({
                name: '__updateById__' + relation,
                isStatic: false
            });
            relationMethods.push({
                name: '__exists__' + relation,
                isStatic: false
            });
            relationMethods.push({
                name: '__link__' + relation,
                isStatic: false
            });
            relationMethods.push({
                name: '__get__' + relation,
                isStatic: false
            });
            relationMethods.push({
                name: '__create__' + relation,
                isStatic: false
            });
            relationMethods.push({
                name: '__update__' + relation,
                isStatic: false
            });
            relationMethods.push({
                name: '__destroy__' + relation,
                isStatic: false
            });
            relationMethods.push({
                name: '__unlink__' + relation,
                isStatic: false
            });
            relationMethods.push({
                name: '__count__' + relation,
                isStatic: false
            });
            relationMethods.push({
                name: '__delete__' + relation,
                isStatic: false
            });
        });
    } catch (err) {}

    methods.concat(relationMethods).forEach(function(method) {
        var methodName = method.name;
        if (methodsToExpose.indexOf(methodName) < 0) {
            hiddenMethods.push(methodName);
            model.disableRemoteMethod(methodName, method.isStatic);
        }
    });

    if (hiddenMethods.length > 0) {
        console.log('\nRemote mehtods hidden for', modelName, ':', hiddenMethods.join(', '), '\n');
        }
    }
};

exports.disableAllMethodsButRemotes = function disableAllMethodsBut(model) {
    var remotes = Object.keys(model.definition.settings.methods || {});
    return exports.disableAllMethodsBut(model, remotes);
};
```

I home it helps someone